# Error while reading the last entry of a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am reading a file using a delimiter with a scanner. When I get to the last entry of the file it says I am out of bounds. If I count correctly I am in bounds though.

Here is the code and it is throwing an input mismatch error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String personName = null;
        double score = 0;

        File myFile = new File("twogrades.dat");

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile).useDelimiter(",");

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                personName = scan.next();

                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    score += ((scan.nextDouble() / 50) * 0.03);
                }

                for (int i = 6; i <= 11; i++) {
                    score += ((scan.nextDouble() / 10) * 0.02);
                }
                score += ((scan.nextDouble()) * 0.20);
                score += ((scan.nextDouble()) * 0.50);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("grades.dat", true)));
                out.println(personName + " " + score);

                out.close();
                score = 0;
                scan.nextLine();
            }

            scan.close();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()
                    + " You entered a wrong data type");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()
                    + " There are no more elements left in the file");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the file

```
Yuri Allen,5,26,16,22,18,3,0,4,4,2,10,2,54,89
```

Comment: could you also provide your `twogrades.dat` file example?

Comment: Read, and post the stack trace of the exception. Use your debugger. Check, and post, your input file.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with data you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the error, but only if there is more than one line in the input file. The problem is the delimiter. You only use the comma `","`. Thus, the scanner tries to read the new line character with the last entry of the line: `"89\n"`. Since this is not a valid double, you get the exception.

You can solve this by adding the new line character as a delimiter: `",|\\r\\n|\\r|\\n"`

Answer (score 0):

I run it and the result is: `No line found There are no more elements left in the file` and the output `Yuri Allen 55.398`. Possibly you can clean, rebuild your project and change:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
```

to this

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
```